# передать в опцию date в ajax переменную от js

Tags: javascript, ajax

Ситуация такая в date не передается содержимое переменной js, то есть  это -  data:({zapros}), должно меняться на data:({city_id:2}), но не получается, подскажите, первый раз работаю с ajax, что я делаю не так? Библиотека подключена, проблема не в этом проверял, если водить в ручную данные в date, все отрабатывает.

```
var zapros = 'city_id:2';

$.ajax ({
    url:'/tpl/catalog/product_list.php',
    type:'GET',
    data:({zapros}),
    dataType:'html',
    success: ajax_success
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В `data` мы можем передать строку или объект.

Пример:

```
var zapros = 'city_id=2';
// или
var zapros = {city_id:2};
```

Результирующий код:

```js
var zapros = 'city_id=2';

$.ajax({
  url: '/tpl/catalog/product_list.php',
  type: 'GET',
  data: zapros,
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```